# Wsl Ubuntu Installation

Tags: boot, gnome, system-installation, windows, system

I was installing wsl on windows 11 and before I finished installing the Ubuntu distro I ran out of wifi so I proceeded to reboot the computer with an incomplete Ubuntu Installation and after restarting my windows operating system crashed  .How do I fix it?

Comment: "*after restarting my windows operating system crashed*" First consult a Windows support venue to fix your Windows crash.